# Solid Shadow in All Directions

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, layer, shadow

I've been looking for a way to set the `shadow` property of a layer, like this: [image]

where the light blue is the layer—the `UIImageView` in this instance—and the dark blue is the shadow.

I'd like the shadow to do things:

- Appear on all four sides: accomplished by setting `shadowOffset` to `CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)` and making `shadowRadius` nonzero
- Be entirely opaque: accomplished by setting `shadowOffset` to a specific point in the layer and `shadowRadius` to zero

I already have `shadowOpacity`set to zero, but I can't find a way to do both of these. For example, if I have:

```
imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4.0 , 4.0)
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 0
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

I get a solid shadow on two sides. If I want the shadow to be on all four sides, I change `shadowOffset` to a specific size and `shadowRadius` to something greater than zero, but then it's not solid.

Comment: Have you tried using `borderWidth`/`borderColor`? Or CAShapeLayer?

Comment: `borderWidth` and `borderColor` are perfect. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative option is to use `borderWidth` and `borderColor`. Keep in mind that, as mentioned in the docs, borders are drawn *inside* the layer bounds, rather than extending outside, so you may need to adjust its size as appropriate.

(Depending on your use case, you might consider using UIImageView with insets to make a stretchable image, which may have different performance characteristics if your layer is being resized.)

Comment: I may have spoken too soon—therein lies the problem. It's a `UIImageView`, so even if I make it larger to compensate for the space lost, will insets make it so the image isn't cropped?

Comment: You might be able to use a combination of the view/layer's contents mode ("center" rather than "fill"/"fit") and adjusting its size. Or, you could prerender a border on the image. You could also try making it a resizable image.

Comment: Do you know how can I change its size? `imageView.image.size` is read-only.

Comment: I mean the view/layer's size.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I'll look for a way to incorporate those so that the image isn't cropped. Meanwhile, I'll accept this answer.