# iOS: Solid Border Outside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uiview, autolayout

A `layer`'s `borderWidth` and `borderColor` properties draw a border *inside* the view. Remykits pointed this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184133/add-a-border-outside-of-a-uiview-instead-of-inside).

A `layer`'s `shadow...` properties cannot be used to create a border that both **appears on all four sides** *and* is **opaque** for reasons I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583323/solid-shadow-in-all-directions).

What I failed to specify in that question (and the reason I've opened a new one) is that I want the border to be **outside the view**. Increasing the `frame` of the view to compensate for the space lost, as has been suggested, doesn't work; I'm using a `UIImageView`, so even if the `frame` is increased, the `image` is still cropped.

Another suggestion was to change the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to `.Center`, in combination with changing the size of the view, but this doesn't work as the view then isn't the proper size.

The solution I first thought of was to create another `UIView` "behind" this `UIImageView`, and give it a `backgroundColor` to mimic the effect of a border. I also thought of creating a custom subclass of `UImageView`. Both courses of action, however, involve making calculations based on the `frame` of the view. I've had many problems with the `frame` not being set by AutoLayout at the proper time, etc.

Other things that come to mind are digitally adding a border to the image or positioning the image in a specific part of the `UIImageView`. (My attempt at the latter was `imageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRectInset(imageView.bounds, 4, 4)`, which resulted in a strangely pixellated image.)

To be clear, what I'm looking for is this: 
[image]

It really feels like there should be a simpler way to do this than creating a new class or view. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to change the `UIImage` size and put it into `UIImageView` which background color is changes as border color? Also set `contentMode` to center. This can be work if you are cropping the image with imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Stitching together aykutt's comment about resizing the image and changing the `conentMode`, Paul Lynch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage) about resizing images, and rene's (life-saving) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629240/ios-autolayout-frame-size-not-set-in-viewdidlayoutsubviews) about what to do your subviews actually *aren't* laid out in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.myContainer.setNeedsLayout()
    self.myContainer.layoutIfNeeded()

    var width: CGFloat = 4 //the same width used for the border of the imageView
    var rect = CGRectInset(imageView.bounds, width, width)
    var size = CGSizeMake(rect.width, rect.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    var new = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.imageView.contentMode = .Center
    self.imageView.image = new

}
```